# Who protects what?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Personal Information Protection and Electronic Documents Act ("PIPEDA"): The Federal legislation that applies to protection of employee personal information by federally-regulated organizations (such as banks and telecommunications companies), as well as protection of personal information in the course of commercial activities in all jurisdictions that do not have similar legislation.

For the first half of the sentence, I can understand the part that "The Federal legislation that applies to protection of employee personal information".

But it is followed by "by federally-regulated organizations (such as banks and telecommunications companies)". I have no idea what this part is related to. Is it talking about the employee personal information or protection?

Comment: *Protection* is derived from the verb *protect*, and like its root verb licenses a *by* preposition phrase to express the Agent of the action: federally-regulated organizations.

Comment: @StoneyB So we can regard it as "The Federal legislation that applies to protection by federally-regulated organizations"? But it is still hard to understand. I can't remember any phrase looks like "noun by something". What does "by" means here?

Comment: It means that the object of *by* is the Agent of the act: it's the organizations that do the protecting.

Comment: _by_ is not the only preposition whose phrases can be licensed by a root verb. Compare _"I **suspect** someone of murder", "I have **suspicion** of murder."_

Comment: It refers to protection. "Protection *of* _____, *by* _____…"

Comment: @P.E.Dant This makes me struggling. There are tons of meaning of the preposition "of". Does it mean to indicate apposition or identity?

Comment: _Of_ in this case means the entity to which protection is given. Don't worry about this: prepositions are among the most difficult words to grasp in English. _Of_ often means "belonging to" in some way, as it does here. It can indicate origin or identity, too. You will see it used with many verbs and nouns ("protection of", e.g.) and it may be easier to consider the entire phrase than to consider the preposition alone.

Comment: @P.E.Dant No, I'm talking about the sentence "I suspect someone of murder" here.

Comment: _Of_ is often used in the construction of verb phrases to indicate the person or thing affected by the action of the verb. After the transitive _suspect,_ the preposition _of_ introduces what the OED calls the "secondary object" (in this case "murder".) In English, we say that a verb _"takes a preposition."_  _Suspect_ means "to believe that something may be true." The verb _suspect_ often takes the preposition _of_ to indicate what "may be true". That is the case in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

There act applies to "federally regulated organizations". It tells them how they must protect employee personal information.

So the pattern that is applied is "Protection of ... by ...". Consider simple examples

> Protection of children by parents.   (Parents protect the children)
>   Protection of wildlife by Park Rangers.   (Park rangers protect the wildlife)

So we understand

> Federally regulated organizations (such as banks) protect employee personal information.

And how the do this is regulated by the act.